# Using INDEX function to derive complete row

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using INDEX function, how do I get the output of an entire row.

[image]

[image]

Using =INDEX(fulltable,4), I expected row 4 as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 0 at the end of the formula. The 0 means that you want to return the whole row as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd):

> If you set row_num or column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively. To use values returned as an array, enter the INDEX function as an array formula.

```
=INDEX(fulltable,4,0)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Just remember to confirm the formula with CTRL+SHFT+ENTER for version of Excel without dynamic array/spilling support i.e. versions prior to Excel 365.